# AngularJS Filter for comma separated values

Tags: angularjs, json

I have one column in my database that has comma separated values for example this is my table:

[image]

Now I want to filter it in my AngularJS Application.

I can filter by name and etc, whoever column has only one single string. However, I'm having difficulty to sort it together if I have to sort it by fruits.

For example: I want to sort who like orange, who likes apple and etc. and I am stuck with this. Perhaps you can help me.

Here is my code in my html file:

```
  <div class="col s12">
                <div class="col s12 input-field">
                    <select
                        ng-model="global.fruitFilter"
                        ng-options="tp.fruits as tp.fruits for tp in tables= (table | filter: {region: global.name||undefined, cluster: global.amount||undefined :true) | unique:'fruit'"
                        material-select watch>
                        <option value="">Select Fruit</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am using ng-options here so everytime I select a fruit, my table will adapt which person has that fruit for example if I pick an Apple, my table will show only data who likes apple: (Rita, Eve).

I have a button on my homepage for filtering its data on the table:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I'm only using one json file

```
{"id":1,"name":"Rita",fruits":["Apple"],["Banana"],["Guava"],"created_at":"2016-08-18 12:33:14","updated_at":"2016-09-22 13:54:01"}
```

I am very new in AngularJS 1. Kindly help me.